# Python3 Virtual Environment and PIP

Tags: python-3.x

I'd like to play around in a virtual environment that's being interpreted purely via python3.3. On my system (Ubuntu 13.04), there are two ways to create a virtual environment.

```
virtualenv env
```

or:

```
pyvenv-3.3 env
```

If I use the old faithful, `virtualenv`, I'm able to use everything as expected, however, PIP installs everything into python2.7 libs rather than python3.3 libs. So, calling scripts using

```
python3 script.py
```

Doesn't seem to work, yet:

```
python script.py
```

Works like a charm. But, obviously must be using python2.7

---

Now, if instead, I use the "built-in" venv from Python3+ (`pyvenv-3.3`), it seems that everything get's a little whacky. It correctly places a python3.3 lib folder in the venv, however, installing modules using PIP is no longer possible as it seems to somehow reference the global rather than the virtual environment.

So, on to my question:

How would you recommend getting a working virtual environment with ONLY Python3.3(+) and PIP installing to python3.3 libs?

Comment: huh.  weird.  i ran `pyvenv-3.3 env` then `source env/bin/activate` then `wget http://python-distribute.org/distribute_setup.py` then `python distribute_setup.py` then `easy_install pip` then `pip install simple-date` and it's trying to install in the system libs.  which sounds like the same issue.  and this is on opensuse.  seems like a bug somewhere.

Comment: Yeah, seems to access system vs. virtual environment. Strange given that it's a venv.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

### You might consider trying something similar to the following:

1. **Create your virtual environment**

   ```
   $ python3 -m venv myvenv
   $ source myvenv/bin/activate
   (myvenv)$
   ```
2. **Install pip according to the [official pip installation instructions](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/).**  *As of pip v1.5.1 you no longer need to manually install setuptools before installing pip.*

   ```
   (myvenv)$ curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python
   ```
3. **Deactivate then reactivate your virtual environment.**  Do this or pip won't work correctly.

   ```
   (myvenv)$ deactivate
   $ source myvenv/bin/activate
   (myvenv)$ which pip
   ```

### Longer response:

Yes, I had a similar problem. It has to do with all the other pythons and pips living on your system and the pip that did not get installed, like it does with the non "core" virtualenv you are used to.

For some reason the venv module does not install setuptools and pip.

I did the above and so far, so good.

venv in [Python 3.3](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/venv.html) does not install pip by itself:

> Common installation tools such as Distribute and pip work as expected with venvs - i.e. when a venv is active, they install Python packages into the venv without needing to be told to do so explicitly. Of course, you need to install them into the venv first.

The [Python 3.4](http://docs.python.org/3.4/library/venv.html) implementation of venv installs pip by default.

> Changed in version 3.4: Installs pip by default

http://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html

You can check your pip with `which pip` and `pip -V`. If you did not deactivate/activate the venv and `pip -V` will not show the correct the correct pip, but `which pip` may still show the correct path.

Comment: I had a similar solution to Matt's except I'm on a mac.  The steps are pretty much the same though. I blogged about the steps here:

http://blog.troygrosfield.com/2014/01/09/python3-virtual-environments/

Comment: Works like charm on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Comment: Might be worth noting that the venv should be re-activated before using pip, otherwise the version of pip used will still be the system version

Comment: I am using python3.6 and pip gets installed by default. 'python3.6 -m venv <path/to/install>'. source path/to/install/bin/activate , then ran pip --version

Answer (score 7):

Here is how I did it (I am on Ubuntu 12.04).

First, install Python 3.3 in a folder, for example `/opt/python3`. Then run the following commands:

```
/opt/python3/bin/pyvenv-3.3 ~/py3  # pyvenv is python3's built-in virtualenv
source ~/py3/bin/activate
curl https://bitbucket.org/pypa/setuptools/raw/bootstrap/ez_setup.py | python
easy_install-3.3 pip
```

Answer (score 5):

The latest version of `pip` has a `pip3` function that will install into your default Python3 instance.

```
pip3 install python_lib
```

If you have both Python 2.x and 3.y on your system, `pip` will install into your Python 2.x and `pip3` into Python 3.y.

Comment: Well doesn't that make it easier.

Answer (score 2):

this works for me:

```
> virtualenv-3.3 env
...
> source env/bin/activate
> pip install simple-date
...
> python
Python 3.3.0 (default, Mar 27 2013, 20:56:52) 
[GCC 4.7.2 20130108 [gcc-4_7-branch revision 195012]] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import simpledate
>>>
```

unfortunately, i'm not completely sure how i installed virtualenv-3.3 back in the day.  i *think* i probably did something like:

```
> wget http://python-distribute.org/distribute_setup.py
> python3.3 distribute_setup.py
> easy_install-3.3 virtualenv
```

[edit: yes, that seems to be confirmed by my notes at http://www.acooke.org/cute/GettingPyt0.html ]

note that is then a python-3.3 specific virtualenv.

as described in the comments, i could not get pyvenv-3.3 to work.

Comment: +1 However, I'm really looking for a working solution with pyvenv-3.3 as there are a few features of the new built in venv that I'm interested in playing with. Appreciate the attempt either way.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on OS X. It looks like even the `pip` executable that gets put in `bin/` by `easy_install` is still meant for Python 2. If you use the `pip3` executable (or variant thereof) it should work just fine!

Answer (score 1):

I have used the [PPA ppa:fkrull/deadsnakes](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/05/install-python-3-3-5-or-3-4-via-ppa-in-ubuntu-14-04-12-04/) to install Python 3.4 in my Elementary Os (a Ubuntu based Linux distribution).

I would like to make one indication. In the Python 3.4 Ubuntu package **when you create a a virtual environment (with *pyvenv-3.4*) pip is installed under *local/bin* instead of *bin*.

So to use it you have to modify the *bin/activate* script at line 44. It should be

```
PATH="$VIRTUAL_ENV/bin:$VIRTUAL_ENV/local/bin:$PATH"
```

Answer (score 0):

It's well mentioned in the docs:

> Common installation tools such as Distribute and pip work as expected with venvs - i.e. when a venv is active, they install Python packages into the venv without needing to be told to do so explicitly. `**`**Of course, you need to install them into the venv first: this could be done by running distribute_setup.py with the venv activated, followed by running easy_install pip**`**`. Alternatively, you could download the source tarballs and run python setup.py install after unpacking, with the venv activated.