# "TypeError: 'str' object is not callable" when creating virtualenv with Python 3.1

Tags: python, virtualenv, python-3.1

This commands on Ubuntu 14.10:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fkrull/deadsnakes -y
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python3.1 python3.1-dev
sudo pip install virtualenv==12.1.1
virtualenv -ppython3.1 env
```

Gives me this:

```
Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/bin/python3.1
New python executable in env/bin/python3.1
Also creating executable in env/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip...
  Complete output from command /home/andrew/project...ib/env/bin/python3.1 -c "import sys, pip; sys...d\"] + sys.argv[1:]))" setuptools pip:
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-6.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/compat/dictconfig.py", line 347, in configure
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-6.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/compat/dictconfig.py", line 454, in configure_filter
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-6.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/compat/dictconfig.py", line 264, in configure_custom
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-6.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/__init__.py", line 217, in main
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-6.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/basecommand.py", line 197, in main
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-6.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/compat/dictconfig.py", line 565, in dictConfig
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-6.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/compat/dictconfig.py", line 348, in configure
NameError: global name 'StandardError' is not defined
```

If somebody share how to deal with it, I will appreciate.

p.s.
I guess this issue can be related to `virtualenv` and `pip` versions.

Comment: python 3 with 2.7?  :/

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Yep. But exactly this commands works with `python3`, `python3.2`, `python3.3` and `python3.4`

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26215790/venv-doesnt-create-activate-script-python3/26314477#26314477